# Expected Card Advantage in YGO - Going beyond the multivariate hypergeometric formula

Tags: probability, references

*Repost from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488099/expected-card-advantage-in-ygo-going-beyond-the-multivariate-hypergeometric-fo). I struggle to get any response to this on MSE and on MO.*

*If you like you can recast everything below as a problem about drawing $k$ balls of $M$ different colors from an urn without replacement.*

There is a famous trading card game that is abbreviated as YGO. In this game you may select the deck of cards you are using yourself before you play.
Naturally, this leads to the overarching question: What cards do I play and in which quantities should I play them? Usually, (but not always) the different types of cards can be written as a partition of the entire deck for the purpose of formulating these questions.

We will be thinking of our opening hand. If we just want to know something like "what is the probability of opening X of card type A" we can use the probability density of the hypergeometric distribution and we can generalize this to more than 2 types of cards using the multivariate hypergeometric distribution.

But the questions that come up are often times significantly more complicated than that.
Instead of probabilities of opening hands I want to generalize to expected "payoffs".
I'll call this expected *card advantage* of our opening hand.

One "simple" definition of expected card advantage could be

$$\mathbb E[\max_{i\leq j \leq M} \lambda_{i,j} 1_{\{n_i \geq 1\}} 1_{\{n_j \geq 1\}}].$$

Here we have partitioned our deck into $M$ classes (types of cards). We draw $k$ cards in our opening hand and $n_i$ is the number of cards in our opening hand that are from class $i$.

In game jargon we would say that the probability $\mathbb P(n_i \geq 1, n_j \geq 1)$ is the probability of *opening a two-card combo* with cards from $i$ and $j$ (although we also include the possibility of *one-card combos*, since we can have $i=j$). Then $\lambda_{i,j}$ would be the card advantage I would get if I played that combo. Usually, I can only play one combo, which is why I always want to play the one generating the maximal card advantage. Hence, the $\max$.

I'm very ignorant about the literature on urn models. I wonder how or whether we can efficiently compute the expected card advantage. My question is:

**Has this or a more general question been studied before and where can I read about that?**

We can probably recast this problem into a purely combinatorial problem, although I'm not sure this will make it easier to find the right book.

I'm not directly interested in solving this from scratch, because it seems quite painful and I wonder how much the insights generalize to more complicated problems. My hope is that there is already a powerful framework for dealing with such questions somewhere.

Comment: Interesting question. As you write, the multivariate hypergeometrical distribution is likely a good starting point. Given your payoffs (getting these is likely to be the *practical* problem), you could probably calculate the expectation by hand, though it would be a bit of a combinatorial nightmare. Alternatively, you could simulate. The problem is that order statistics (your max) are hard to pin down by simulation, so you might need a prohibitive amount of simulations to get reliable results.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Simulation is what I've done in the past, personally. I also know of one instance where "professionals" have done the same to develop a strategy that got favorable tournament results ("60-card Dragon link"). But it's a cumbersome process. The worst thing though is that really the goal is to *optimize* over the objective (or a similar objective), so you would need to compute Monte-carlo estimates of these expectations over and over for slightly different $\lambda$s. I'm just wondering whether this is actually an old problem that has already been solved analytically.